# hide duplicate row sql

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

How to hide/remove duplicate row from this query

```
SELECT 
    CASE
       WHEN capex_billofmaterialitem.decQuantity <> '0'
         THEN '0'
         ELSE capex_billofmaterialitem.decQuantity
    END AS decQuantity,
    capex_billofmaterialitem.*
FROM 
    capex_billofmaterialitem,
    capex_billofmaterial
WHERE 
    capex_billofmaterialitem.szbillofmaterialid = capex_billofmaterial.szbillofmaterialid
    AND capex_billofmaterial.szprojectcode = '" + szProjectCode + "'";
```

Comment: use `Distinct` ...........

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Can you include sample records for your tables and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `DISTINCT` -

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE
           WHEN capex_billofmaterialitem.decQuantity <> '0'
               THEN '0'
           ELSE capex_billofmaterialitem.decQuantity
       END AS decQuantity,
       capex_billofmaterialitem.*
FROM capex_billofmaterialitem
JOIN capex_billofmaterial ON capex_billofmaterialitem.szbillofmaterialid = capex_billofmaterial.szbillofmaterialid
WHERE capex_billofmaterial.szprojectcode = @szProjectCode
```

Comment: @Ubay Maulana please provide actual and expected results

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

> **using row_number() this is safe method**

```
WITH CTE_Dup AS
(

 SELECT * ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITIONBY SalesOrderno, ItemNo ORDER BY SalesOrderno, ItemNo)
 AS ROW_NO
 from dbo.SalesOrderDetails
)
Delete FROM CTE_Dup;
```